# icons and their color are updating automatically | iOS | CarbonKit

Tags: ios, swift, carbonkit

I'm using CarbonTabSwipeNavigation in my code (as follows). The issue is that the colour of all the icons is being updated automatically (probably to some default colour). How to fix that?
Apart from that, one of my icons is being updated (don't know why). I tried using the same icon in other parts of the application and it worked perfectly fine. Please help me in this. Thanks

```
weak var tab: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()        
let iconNames = ["icn_events", "icn_places", "icn_activities", "icn_clubs"]
var images = [UIImage]()

for icon in iconNames {
    if let img = UIImage(named: icon) {
        images.append(img)
    }
}

let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: images, delegate: self)
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.pagesScrollView?.isScrollEnabled = false
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)

//I'm using following piece of code to fix the color issue (please note, even without this, the image is being updated). 
//carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setNormalColor(UIColor(hex: "5603ad"))
//carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor(hex: "5603ad"))

carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabExtraWidth(45)

tab = carbonTabSwipeNavigation
}
```

I've attached the actual icon and the screenshot of how it's being displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because of bar tint color. The issue was fixed the issue by image rendering mode:

```
let iconNames = ["icn_events", "icn_places", "icn_activities"]
var images = [UIImage]()

for icon in iconNames {
    if let img = UIImage(named: icon) {
        images.append(img)
    }
}

if let img = UIImage(named: "icn_clubs")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal) {
    images.append(img)
}
```